# ListView using UniversalImageLoader not updating images

Tags: android, listview, universal-image-loader

I have a `ListView` with a custom `ListAdapter`:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.DisplayImageOptions;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.assist.ImageSize;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.listener.SimpleImageLoadingListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Tukajo on 10/1/2015.
 */
public class CharacterListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Character> implements ResourceDownloader.OnTaskCompleted {
    private ImageView charImgView = null;

    public CharacterListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
    }

    public CharacterListAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Character> items) {
        super(context, resource, items);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi;
            vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.custom_character_list_row, null);
        }

        Character p = getItem(position);
        charImgView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.characterImageView);
        if (p != null) {
            ImageSize targetSize = new ImageSize(200, 200);
            ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
            DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.ic_person_brown_600_48dp)
                    .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_person_brown_600_48dp)
                    .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_person_brown_600_48dp)
                    .cacheInMemory(false)
                    .cacheOnDisk(true)
                    .build();
            imageLoader.loadImage(p.getPhoto(), targetSize, options, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                    charImgView.setImageBitmap(loadedImage);
                }
            });

        }

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskCompleted(Bitmap bitmap) {
        charImgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

However running the list, I get the images "loading" in storage, but the default drawables are still loading.

Here is a screenshot with what I mean:

[image]

Comment: have you tried implementing other listener methods like errorListeners and loging the result?

Comment: Yeah the issue is more so that I can load the images, but they swap around like crazy. Like if I scroll up, a bunch of images will load but they will swap around. I think the issue has to do with the listview recycling. Not sure how to fix that.

Comment: add .resetViewBeforeLoading(true) in display image options EDIT: sorry this will not work because you have loaded image in view using listener. Why are you not using imagloader.displayImage method instead ?? if you are loading this way you have to cancel if previous image loading task exist and also set plageholder before calling imageLoader.loadImage

Comment: Changing to `displayImage` it works, but then it resizes them.

Comment: It resizes image because you may have wrap_content attribute to layout width or/and height, you can set height and width of imageview before loading so it wont resize